# add_options_page() & __FILE__ issue

Tags: wordpress, file

When I use 
`add_options_page( $page_title, $menu_title, $capability, $menu_slug, $function);` Here when I add `__FILE__` for `$menu_slug` as  `add_options_page( $page_title, $menu_title, $capability, __FILE__, $function);`  then I get only folder name and file name in the menu slug, like this *http://localhost/wp-site-name/wp-admin/options-general.php?page=folder-name/file-name.php* where `__FILE__` represents the full path. How it happens?

Answer (score 0):

You should give a menu slug, instead of `__FILE__`. For example: `"my-menu"`.

If you have trouble with adding settings pages, I can point you to a class that I recently created, that handles this kind of job and makes things much easier for you. I created it out of frustration with the WP Settings API - obviously ;)

Comment: Thanks @Sorin 
The `__FILE__` is working fine for me & if I add a menu_slug instead of `__FILE__`  that's also works but my question is different here. I want to understand the things why `__FILE__` output only the `dir_name/file_name` ?

Comment: That's what `__FILE__` does. It gives you the **local** path to the file (with file name included). It has nothing to do with Wordpress, but with the way PHP works. Please check the magic constants page to see the definition: [Magic Constants in PHP](http://php.net/manual/ro/language.constants.predefined.php)

Comment: Thanks @Sorin I understand That.